# How do people show limit in the past?

Tags: analysis, limits

How do people express the idea of limit before using $\varepsilon-N$ and $\varepsilon-\delta$ to express?

Comment: You do not need $\epsilon$-$\delta$ or $N$ to argue convincingly in concrete cases.

Comment: What about proving theorems?

Comment: That is another issue. There were (though rarely) some mistakes made, mostly in interchanging limits.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you asked, but I know that Leibniz, the rivalry of Newton, tried to establish calculus for infinitesimals, but in vain. That is why Newton's limiting process prevailed in calculus.

However, ideas of Leibniz were picked up again in the 20th century, and people call it [non-standard analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis).

Comment: To be more specific, how do people show $\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\dfrac{x^{2}-1}{x-1}=2$?